# Laravel relationship eloquent

Tags: laravel

I have my model like this:   Product has a relation with country

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function country()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Country','countrie_id');
    }
}
```

I have this query in my controller:

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
```

It returns:

```
        "id": 1,
        "categorie_id": 1,
        "countrie_id": 1,
        "solution_id": 1,
        "line_id": 1,
        "name": "COLAGEN PREMIUN",
        "internal_code": "1321368478978",
        "description": "FSDFSDF",
        "composition": "colageno de acido citrico",
        "benefits": "ayuda a al anemia",
        "price": 250,
        "price_sale": 500,
        "active": 1
```

I'd like to know how to retrive the country name and not the country_id with that relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with on your Eloquent product model

```
$products = Product::with('country')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
```

In your view you now can use:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{$product->country->name}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get country name via foreach loop in blade

```
@foreach($products as $product)
{{$product->country->name}}
@endforeach
```